# How to fix TransactionTooLargeException when using viewPager2 with a lot of fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, transactiontoolargeexception

I have a case where I want to use viewPager2 with dynamic number of fragments, sometimes they are 1000+ fragments, each fragment contains a "long" argument.
The issue is when i navigate to a large number of fragments (50+) and then put the app in background, I will get TransactionTooLargeException.
From the logs it looks that the parcel size is too large because of "android:support:fragments".

This is the FragmentStateAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter(fragment: Fragment, private val ids: List<Long>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = ids.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(ids[position])
    }
}
```

and this is the logs:

> E  !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1617044)
> W  Bundle stats:
> W    androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key [size=1615712]
> W      android:support:activity-result [size=6192]
> W        KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS [size=5524]
> W      android:support:fragments [size=1608532]
> W        fragment_153267f4-13db-4e3e-aadc-397b3613c3b0 [size=1608036]
> W  Ignoring header If-None-Match because its value was null.
> W          childFragmentManager [size=1604160]
> W            fragment_5e76ed4f-86c4-4abd-b180-a266b7ecb7ec [size=3432]
> W              viewState [size=1480]
> W            state [size=2492]
> W            fragment_e8dab6b8-c161-4b3f-bfc2-5e8144a830b5 [size=1589116]
> W              viewState [size=1562464]
> W                0x7f0a075f [size=1561320]
> W              childFragmentManager [size=25000]
> W                fragment_d802e2b3-6eab-4b0c-ab8f-58f71bd734c4 [size=5968]
> W                  viewState [size=4432]
> W                fragment_c9746424-d404-43a8-9886-5c7107e952a9 [size=5968]
> W                  viewState [size=4432]
> W                fragment_d34a0450-4f4d-4c7f-9291-a4bdb9a127c3 [size=5908]
> W                  viewState [size=4372]
> W                fragment_bfc173a7-454f-4313-b309-68256713769e [size=5968]
> W                  viewState [size=4432]
> W            fragment_a78c4302-7fb2-4e0c-9c6f-8eab1c57afdc [size=4908]
> W              viewState [size=1572]
> W              childFragmentManager [size=2536]
> W                fragment_02f2a322-316e-4560-8ded-ceeefdfd9222 [size=2116]
> W            fragment_051e13d4-04fc-4571-a076-48795ec8cbef [size=3796]
> W              viewState [size=2040]
> W          registryState [size=3184]
> W            androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key [size=3060]
> W              android-support-nav:fragment:navControllerState [size=2640]
> W                android-support-nav:controller:backStack [size=2536]
> W  PersistableBundle stats:
> W    [null]

I have tried to comment out onSavedInstanceState method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Users are unlikely to be willing to page through 1000 pages in a pager. Beyond that, your problem lies in the implementation of `MyFragment`. Its UI is adding too much to the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: this is an inventory app, and users may spent hours counting through swiping between items, is there a way to clear the saved instance state, or should i look for an alternative of view pager?